# No Edit / Delete Links for Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-editor

I've created a custom post type for "testimonials" as well as rearranged the edit post display with custom columns for that post type... Everything works as expected EXCEPT for the fact that when I hover over one of these custom posts, the list of "action links" that normally appears beneath it enabling you to edit/delete that post aren't there...

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Here's all the related code:

```
function wpg_edit_testimonials_columns($columns) {
  $columns = array(
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'testimonial_author' => __('Author', 'quotable'),
    'testimonial_text' => __('Testimonial', 'quotable'),
    'attribution_link' => __('Attribution Link', 'quotable'),
    'date' => __('Date Added', 'quotable')
  );
  return $columns;
}

function wpg_manage_testimonials_columns($column, $post_id) {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $testimonial_author_name = $custom['testimonial_author_name'][0];
  $testimonial_author_link = $custom['testimonial_author_link'][0];

  switch($column) {

    case 'testimonial_author':
      echo $testimonial_author_name;
    break;

    case 'testimonial_text':
      echo $post->post_content;
    break;

    case 'attribution_link':
      echo $testimonial_author_link;
    break;

    default :
      break;
  }
}
add_filter('manage_edit-testimonials_columns', 'wpg_edit_testimonials_columns');
add_action('manage_testimonials_posts_custom_column', 'wpg_manage_testimonials_columns', 10, 2);
```

My only guess is that maybe it has something to do with the fact that the "title" column isn't being used? I didn't see any need in using the title column since the post type doesn't even support the use of "titles", as it's just a testimonial.

### EDIT:

Ok, I've confirmed that it is, in fact, due to the fact that the title column isn't being used... I added "title" to the list of columns in the array and the links appeared... However, since titles aren't supported in this post type, the title is being listed as "Auto Draft" for all of the testimonials.

### EDIT AGAIN:

Taking the advice of [@helenhousandi](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2226/helenhousandi), I've rolled my own set of links... but now I'm running into an entirely new problem. The delete/trash link uses a nonce, which I've added... but I'm apparently missing a step somewhere, because it's not actually completing the action when clicked.

Instead I'm getting a WordPress failure notice:
[image]

Here's the edited portion of my code:

```
$wpg_row_actions  = '<div class="row-actions"><span class="edit"><a title="'.__('Edit this item', 'quotable').'" href="'.get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=edit">Edit</a> | </span>';
$wpg_row_actions .= '<span class="inline hide-if-no-js"><a title="'.__('Edit this item inline', 'quotable').'" class="editinline" href="#">Quick&nbsp;Edit</a> | </span>';
$wpg_row_actions .= '<span class="trash"><a href="'.wp_nonce_url(get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=trash', 'delete-post_'.$post->ID).'" title="'.__('Move this item to the Trash', 'quotable').'" class="submitdelete">Trash</a></span>';


switch($column) {
  case 'testimonial_author':
    echo $testimonial_author_name.$wpg_row_actions;
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it may not be the most efficient method... but I've found a solution. In the end, I wound up having to write a custom function to handle the addition of the row actions for each post. Here's how it turned out:

```
function wpg_row_actions() {
  global $post;
  if($post->post_type == 'page') {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_page')) {
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_post')) {
      return;
    }
  }
  if($post->post_status == 'trash') {
    $actionLinks  = '<div class="row-actions"><span class="untrash"><a title="'.__('Restore this item', 'quotable').'" href="'.wp_nonce_url(get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=untrash', 'untrash-'.$post->post_type.'_'.$post->ID).'">'.__('Restore', 'quotable').'</a> | </span>';
    $actionLinks .= '<span class="trash"><a href="'.wp_nonce_url(get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=delete', 'delete-'.$post->post_type.'_'.$post->ID).'" title="'.__('Delete this item permanently', 'quotable').'" class="submitdelete">'.__('Delete Permanently', 'quotable').'</a></span>';
  }
  else {
    $actionLinks  = '<div class="row-actions"><span class="edit"><a title="'.__('Edit this item', 'quotable').'" href="'.get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=edit">'.__('Edit', 'quotable').'</a> | </span>';
    $actionLinks .= '<span class="inline hide-if-no-js"><a title="'.__('Edit this item inline', 'quotable').'" class="editinline" href="#">'.__('Quick Edit', 'quotable').'</a> | </span>';
    $actionLinks .= '<span class="trash"><a href="'.wp_nonce_url(get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&amp;action=trash', 'trash-'.$post->post_type.'_'.$post->ID).'" title="'.__('Move this item to the Trash', 'quotable').'" class="submitdelete">'._x('Trash', 'verb (ie. trash this post)', 'quotable').'</a></span>';
  }
  return $actionLinks;
}


function wpg_edit_testimonials_columns($columns) {
  $columns = array(
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'testimonial_author' => __('Author', 'quotable'),
    'testimonial_text' => __('Testimonial', 'quotable'),
    'attribution_link' => __('Attribution Link', 'quotable'),
    'date' => __('Date Added', 'quotable')
  );
  return $columns;
}

function wpg_manage_testimonials_columns($column, $post_id) {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $testimonial_author_name = $custom['testimonial_author_name'][0];
  $testimonial_author_link = $custom['testimonial_author_link'][0];

  $wpg_row_actions  = wpg_row_actions();


  switch($column) {
    case 'testimonial_author':
      echo $testimonial_author_name.$wpg_row_actions;
    break;

    case 'testimonial_text':
      echo $post->post_content;
    break;

    case 'attribution_link':
      echo $testimonial_author_link;
    break;

    default :
      break;
  }
}
add_filter('manage_edit-testimonials_columns', 'wpg_edit_testimonials_columns');
add_action('manage_testimonials_posts_custom_column', 'wpg_manage_testimonials_columns', 10, 2);
```

The function handles checking to see which version of the row actions needs to be added based on whether you're viewing the trashed posts or regular ones. Hopefully this will save someone else hours of frustration later on down the road.

It seems now, however, that I've stumbled onto an entirely new problem. The custom fields data for each post in this custom post type gets deleted when I "trash" one of them... but [that's a new question entirely](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32010/custom-field-values-deleted-when-trashing-custom-post-type).

Answer (score 2):

Correct, without the title column, the row actions don't have a place to show. I haven't tried doing this before, but take a look at the `row_actions()` method in the `WP_List_Table` class. You may not be able to call it directly, but it should show you how those links are built so you can roll them yourself if you need to.

Comment: Any ideas about what I put in my edits above? Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I've got it figured out... but I apparently don't have enough rep to answer my own question. lol

Comment: Does that mean you got the nonce working? If so, good :) Can't help you about answering your own question, though.

Comment: yea, I got it figured out... once my 8hr restriction to answering my own question elapses I'll post the full working solution so that hopefully it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I only wanted the edit button back because alot of the other things can be accomplished either using the bulk actions or inside the actual post so I just retrieved the url of the wordpress site and the post ID and created my own edit link.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$weburl = get_bloginfo('url');
$_cmb_ = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$linktext = $_cmb_["_cmb_link_text"][0];
$linkurl = $_cmb_["_cmb_link_url"][0];
```

And then in the column output

```
case "link_text":
echo '<b>'.$linktext.'</b><br> <a href="'.$weburl.'/wp-admin/post.php?post='.$postid.'&action=edit" title="Edit">Edit</a><br/>';
break;
```

Hope this helps people who are after a simple answer and just for the edit link.