# Custom post type: Add "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View" links to date (if title is not shown in column)?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I've created a custom post type for my "Testimonials", I don't need a title(s), how can I write a function that Adds the "*Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View*" links to "date" if title isn't shown in the column.

I'm using the plugin "Admin Columns" to hide the columns I don't wish to show.

[image: base]

I'm trying to re-use this code from this previous StackExchange question ( [No Edit / Delete Links for Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/no-edit-delete-links-for-custom-post-type) ), however I have already created the fields "Author" etc.

Using this code gives this result.

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easily done as there is no hook to add the rows actions. You can however, unregister the date column and re-register your own date column with the row actions added. A bit hacky unfortunately.

*I have tried to ensure that the following code is for post type 'testimonials'*

First register your new date column and unregister the old: (use `manage_{post_type}_posts_columns` hook)

```
add_filter('manage_testimonials_posts_columns', 'my_custom_date_column_head'); 
function my_custom_date_column_head($columns) {  
    $columns['date2'] = 'Date';  
    unset( $columns['date'] );
    return $columns;  
}
```

Then make your new date column sortable, (by 'date'). Use `manage_edit-{post_type}_sortable_columns` hook)

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-testimonials_sortable_columns', 'my_custom_date_column_sort' );
function my_custom_date_column_sort( $columns ) {
    $columns['date2'] = 'date';
    return $columns;
}
```

Now comes the fun bit - displaying the content of the column. I have pretty much copied and pasted what WordPress does to fill the date column and then added the actions onto the end.

Use `manage_{post_type}_posts_custom_columns` hook)

```
add_action( "manage_testimonials_posts_custom_column", 'my_custom_date_column_content',10,2);
function my_custom_date_column_content($column, $post_id ){
    global $post,$mode;

    if( 'date2' != $column )
        return;

    //**** Display default content of date column *******//

    if ( '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post->post_date ) {
        $t_time = $h_time = __( 'Unpublished' );
        $time_diff = 0;
    } else {
        $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A' ) );
        $m_time = $post->post_date;
        $time = get_post_time( 'G', true, $post );

        $time_diff = time() - $time;

        if ( $time_diff > 0 && $time_diff < 24*60*60 )
            $h_time = sprintf( __( '%s ago' ), human_time_diff( $time ) );
        else
            $h_time = mysql2date( __( 'Y/m/d' ), $m_time );
    }

    if ( 'excerpt' == $mode )
        echo apply_filters( 'post_date_column_time', $t_time, $post, $column, $mode );
    else
        echo '<abbr title="' . $t_time . '">' . apply_filters( 'post_date_column_time', $h_time, $post, $column, $mode ) . '</abbr>';

    echo '<br />';

    if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
        _e( 'Published' );

    } elseif ( 'future' == $post->post_status ) {
        if ( $time_diff > 0 )
            echo '<strong class="attention">' . __( 'Missed schedule' ) . '</strong>';
        else
        _e( 'Scheduled' );

    } else {
        _e( 'Last Modified' );
    }

    //***** END  -- Display default content of date column *******//


    //***** START  -- Our actions  *******//

    //First set up some variables
    $actions = array();
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    $can_edit_post = current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->edit_post, $post->ID );


    //Actions to edit
    if ( $can_edit_post && 'trash' != $post->post_status ) {
        $actions['edit'] = '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link( $post->ID, true ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( __( 'Edit this item' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Edit' ) . '</a>';
        $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] = '<a href="#" class="editinline" title="' . esc_attr( __( 'Edit this item inline' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Quick&nbsp;Edit' ) . '</a>';
    }

    //Actions to delete/trash
    if ( current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) ) {
        if ( 'trash' == $post->post_status )
            $actions['untrash'] = "<a title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Restore this item from the Trash' ) ) . "' href='" . wp_nonce_url( admin_url( sprintf( $post_type_object->_edit_link . '&amp;action=untrash', $post->ID ) ), 'untrash-' . $post->post_type . '_' . $post->ID ) . "'>" . __( 'Restore' ) . "</a>";

        elseif ( EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
            $actions['trash'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Move this item to the Trash' ) ) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) . "'>" . __( 'Trash' ) . "</a>";

        if ( 'trash' == $post->post_status || !EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
            $actions['delete'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Delete this item permanently' ) ) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link( $post->ID, '', true ) . "'>" . __( 'Delete Permanently' ) . "</a>";
    }

    //Actions to view/preview
        if ( in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'pending', 'draft', 'future' ) ) ) {
            if ( $can_edit_post )
                $actions['view'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Preview &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), $title ) ) . '" rel="permalink">' . __( 'Preview' ) . '</a>';

        } elseif ( 'trash' != $post->post_status ) {
                $actions['view'] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), $title ) ) . '" rel="permalink">' . __( 'View' ) . '</a>';
        }

    //***** END  -- Our actions  *******//

    //Echo the 'actions' HTML, let WP_List_Table do the hard work
    echo WP_List_Table::row_actions( $actions );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I tried copying this code to my functions.php file however It did not work. What would you suggest I try?

Comment: In what sense did not work? Did the new column not appear? Did it not containing anything, did it nor sort? Put [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) on while developing as this will help identify errors.

Comment: The date column showed up but that's it.

Comment: And what is the error with debug mode on?

Comment: When I use debug mode eg. (http://localhost/salwaydesigns/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=testimonials?debug=debug) it says "Invalid post type" before and after implementing your code. I will have to correct the testimonials post type.. What would cause this?

Comment: That's not debug mode. See codex page linked in my previous comments. You need to temporarily edit your `wp-config` file.

Comment: I added the code to the wp-config.php file?

Comment: No! Read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) - section 2.9. You need to define `WP_DEBUG` to be true at the top of your `wp-config.php` file. Then any errors will be displayed (they may be hidden under the admin bar). This should only be set to true for development / debugging.

Comment: There are lots of "notices" when using debug mode.. Viewing the edit.php?post_type=testimonials eg Notice: class-snoopy.php is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wp-includes/http.php instead. in C:\wamp\www\salwaydesigns\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3507, Notice: automatic_feed_links is deprecated since version 3.0! Use add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' ) instead. in C:\wamp\www\salwaydesigns\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3467, Notice: Use of undefined constant core_mods - assumed 'core_mods' in C:\wamp\www\salwaydesigns\wp-content\themes\salwaydesigns\functions.php on line 14,

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: ACF_Taxonomy_Field::$l10n_doamin in C:\wamp\www\salwaydesigns\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields-taxonomy-field-add-on\taxonomy-field.php on line 109, Notice: wp_tiny_mce is deprecated since version 3.3! Use wp_editor() instead. in C:\wamp\www\salwaydesigns\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3467

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2946/discussion-between-josh-and-stephen-harris)

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is old, but i add a better answer working since Wordpress 4.3. You can use a filter to assign the primary column of the table. For this solution you need to know the Post Type, and the column ID (inspect the html with your browser to find it).
In my example the post type is "event" (so the variable $screen is "edit-event"), and the column is a custom taxonomy "event-places" (WP is calling the column "taxonomy-event-places").

```
add_filter( 'list_table_primary_column', 'fix_actions_primary_column', 10, 2 );
function fix_actions_primary_column( $default, $screen ) {
    if ( 'edit-event' === $screen ) {
        $default = 'taxonomy-event-places';
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer. Thanks!